# Error from launching pr2.launch

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using Ubuntu Precise with ROS fuerte. I tried to launch pr2 in gazebo but it seems the environment/installation is sort-of unstable. Sometimes it load pr2 properly and can be shown all sensors in Rviz, but not for other times.

Now, I'm having this kind of error when I launched pr2.launch:

```
process[l_gripper_controller/gripper_action_node-23]: started with pid [16238]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[head_traj_controller/point_head_action-24]: started with pid [16290]
[ INFO] [1351477497.008004656]: Starting to spin camera_synchronizer at 100.000000 Hz...
[ WARN] [1351477497.091740736]: You've passed in true for auto_start for the C++ action server at [/tf2_buffer_server]. You should always pass in false to avoid race conditions.
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[torso_controller/position_joint_action_node-25]: started with pid [16332]
loading model xml from ros parameter
[INFO] [WallTime: 1351477498.895346] [0.000000] waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[ WARN] [1351477500.911866367, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/narrow_stereo/left/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477500.912455303, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/narrow_stereo/left/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477500.912905660, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/narrow_stereo/right/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477500.914008002, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/narrow_stereo/right/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477500.951221160, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/wide_stereo/left/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477500.952384603, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/wide_stereo/left/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477500.953034705, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/wide_stereo/right/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477500.953666544, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/wide_stereo/right/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477501.051290564, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/narrow_stereo/left/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477501.051599616, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/narrow_stereo/left/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477501.052576695, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/narrow_stereo/right/image_raw' is not yet advertised
[ WARN] [1351477501.052867741, 1794.089000000]: The input topic '/narrow_stereo/right/camera_info' is not yet advertised
[ INFO] [1351477503.342669484, 1794.089000000]: advertised as /narrow_stereo_textured/left/camera_info

[ INFO] [1351477503.639885288, 1794.089000000]: advertised as /narrow_stereo_textured/right/camera_info

Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
```

I might think that this is caused by gazebo_plugins?? Should I reinstall this package? or by other reasons??

Edit 01: I runs properly again??!!
It's so disappointing that after switching/restarting a few times from Ubuntu to Win7 (Dual OS). ROS successfully loads PR2.launch. I'm confused now!! ROS/gazebo is unstable or something else ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/112/error-from-launching-pr2.launch/) by [ROSbeginner](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/67/rosbeginner/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-01-14**:
sometimes orphaned ros nodes from previous run can cause instability too.  it helps to make sure everything is brought down properly before roslaunching again.

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-01-14**:
I'd say there's a bit of instability during the transition from gazebo 0.9.x to gazebo 1.1.x because of a bunch of new features being introduced and code refactoring. Starting with 1.2, things're more stable again, and thanks to bitbucket pull request reviews :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Unfortunately, fuerte is a bit more unstable, it's a struggle for trade off of new features and stability. I'd recommend going onto groovy for better (new feature)/(stability) ratio.

That said, out of the list of errors provided above, only this one stands out as abnormal:

```
Service call failed: transport error completing service call: unable to receive data from sender, check sender's logs for details
```

This should have been fixed in latest release of fuerte (simulator_gazebo 1.6.16), please verify.

The other simulation warnings are fine, and python errors:

```
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in  ignored
process[head_traj_controller/point_head_action-24]: started with pid [16290]
```

should not affect operation.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1